# How to join two sheets based on calculated fields in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns, calculated-field

**UPDATE**

Source example:

```
Company  yearA  yearB
A        2021   2022
B        2021   2021
C        2021   2023
D        2023   2024
E        2024   2022
```

Table I want to get:

```
year  countA  countB
2021  3       1
2022  0       2
2023  1       1
2024  1       1
```

I am new to Tableau and I find it diffcult to get the joined table based on two caculated fields.
Four fields in Table A and Table B are calculated fields obtained from the fields in one table in the data source. I want to get the “Count table”, which is joint by yearA in TableA == yearB in TableB.

I have tried two methods:

1. Create calculated fields in data source, but some calculated fields do not appear after I create it.
2. Drag four fields yearA, countA, yearB, countB together in one sheet, but I cannot get one(yearA)-to-all(yearB) relationship (Joint Table)since some entries do not appear  in the table in the data source. (For example, the entry “yearA=2022 and yearB=2022” do not appear in the original table)

```
TableA
yearA   countA
2021    1
2022    2
2023    3
```

```
TableB
yearA   countA
2021    4
2022    5
2023    6
```

```
Count table
year   countA  countB
2021   1       4
2022   2       5
2023   3       6
```

```
Joint Table
yearA  countA   yearB  countB
2021     1      2021    4
                2022    5
2022     2      2021    4
                2023    6
2023     3      2021    4
                2022    5
                2023    6
```

Comment: You should not need to "join" sheets if the sheets are from the same data source (unless you have loaded the same source twice as two separate sources). The relationships are defined in the data source and no calculation you do can change that. What doe the source look like and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have already updated the source table and the table I want to get, please help me see how I can solve the problem, thanks!